# Opel astra H crankshaft sensor issue

Tags: engine, crankshaft

I have replaced the crankshaft sensor on my opel astra H 2007. The question I still can not answer is where all those turnings are coming from. The mechanic told me they arr not from the engine side, however I have some doubts if they are coming from the engine 
[image: Crankshaft sensor]
[image: Crankshaft turnings]

Comment: What is your specific engine?